# Spring Batch Integration with HazelCast

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing, hazelcast

I am new to HazelCast . is there any integration of hazelCast with Spring batch.

if yes please let me know most suitable reader in spring batch with Hazel cast object grid as source.

The below link provides  the list of readers for multiple resources.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/listOfReadersAndWriters.html

But i am not able to find the most suitable reader for it.

If no, Do we need write any custom reader for it ?

Answer (score 2):

Hazelcast doesn't provide Spring Batch integration as of now. It'll probably be implemented in the future. Anyhow you might be interested to work on that yourself and contribute it to Hazelcast in form of an enhancement proposal (https://hazelcast.atlassian.net/wiki/display/COM/Hazelcast+Enhancement+Proposals).

For the original answer please see the answer in the Google Group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/hazelcast/poNvf8_GDvQ/BeRr_-u_AAAJ) - I guess it was you :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11648964)

Comment: Added more value to the answer